# Why doesn't a map in a watchOS 5 app show in the Simulator?

Tags: xcode, mapkit, watchkit

I want to show a map in a watchkit app. When I use the code below, I can see my pin annotation, but not the map itself.  Please see the image for illustration.

[image]

I'm running Xcode 10.2.1. With this version I can only run on the Simulator, as this version of Xcode won't run on my series 4 watch. Please see my code below:

```
 override func willActivate() {

        super.willActivate()

        location.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees(lat))
        location.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees(lon))

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        let spanX: Float = 0.005
        let spanY: Float = 0.005


        region.center = location
        region.span.latitudeDelta = CLLocationDegrees(spanX)
        region.span.longitudeDelta = CLLocationDegrees(spanY)
        stationMap.setRegion(region)


        stationMap.addAnnotation(location, with: .red)
    }
```

I may be missing or incorrectly calling the map.

Comment: I have made a separate watch app just to test the map. This has fixed coordinates. Same result

Comment: This may be a simulator bug. I just launched the built-in maps app on a Series 4 watch in the simulator, set it's location to Apple, and opened the map. I can't post a picture in a comment but I'm getting the same result as you're seeing.

Comment: I see it was a known issue in watchOS 2. Though I can't find a reference for it in watchOS 5. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/RN-watchOSSDK-2.0/index.html

Comment: Dan, thanks. How do you find known issues? Thanks

Comment: I did a google search for known watchOS map issues, since I was seeing the same thing. The release notes came up. Here's a link to the latest watchOS notes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchos_release_notes

Comment: Thanks again. There is a reference in the Apple Release notes, to run a command to enable development on my physical watch. That does not work as well. I guess I should file a new bug report